# Achieve breadcrumb with fragment and viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager, breadcrumbs

I want to achieve the breadcrumbs like the image given, till now i have done the screen with tabs with help of viewpager and fragments, but stuck at the breadcrumbs part, i want to make it like some of the file managers applications out in the play store. Any help is appreciated[image: image2] [image: this is what i want to achieve]

Comment: Try using recyclerview with gridlayout

Comment: my main problem is with the breadcrumb and its functionality, rest of the layout is already done with recyclerview with gridlayout @SaravInfern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see my example at https://github.com/digounet/Breadcrumbs
It show how to implement a breadcrumb by using viewpager and tablayout

[image]

Comment: Suggested example is actually a redesign of tab names on toolbar. Not really breadcrumbs. The question demands breadcrumbs within one tab (fragment).